# How to create a measure that show the count on previous month (PowerBI)

Tags: date, powerbi

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to create a column in the matrix table to show the count of `OK` for previous month, I named the measure as `Prev Month OK count` as shown in the screenshot above. However, the output is not what I want based on what I tried. This is my formula:

```
Prev Month OK count = CALCULATE([OK count], DATEADD('Aggregate'[Intake],-1,MONTH))
```

Even I change the `MONTH` parameter to `QUARTER` in `DATEADD`, it doesn't work as well, there is only a value in the Total which I'm not sure what does the value means.

[image]

The screenshot above is the expected output that I want. Take note that `[OK count]` is also a measure.

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

## Screenshot for Date Column

[image]

Comment: If month names are Text, you need another column to order your rows correctly. Then create an index column and finally you can get previous row's value using DAX.

Comment: The month name is not in text, it is a date, any idea why it behave like this ?

Comment: Then please add data that represents your real scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by real scenario? This is already the real scenario, the Month column is in Date format already. The reason why it only show `March`, `June`, `September` and `November` is because I only have data for these 4 months, the rest of the months are empty (no data). Not sure whether I answered your concern.

Comment: Show date in format you have in the table. Do you have single row per month? or multiple? If multiple, do you consider aggregation on month level? or prev value for the last available date?

Comment: I already edited my question with screenshot of my date column. Basically there are only 4 dates, which means all the records are being made on the same date which is 21st of the month. Hope this can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in **Power Query** and create a new table using this following code-

> let your table name is **your_old_table_name**

> let you have these 2 column there - **date** and **value**

Now create a new table **your_new_table_name" as below-

```
let
    Source = your_old_table_name,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"date"}, {{"_sum", each List.Sum([value]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each [Index] + 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Index"}, #"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"_sum"}, {"Added Custom._sum"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Added Custom",{"Index", "Custom"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Added Custom._sum", "previous_date_sum"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

You will have an output similar as below-

[image]